# A problem involving normalizer of a isotropy group

Tags: group-theory

The problem is in the proof of the  following lemma:

Suppose $G$ is a group that acts transitively on $S$. Take $s \in S$ and define $G_s=\{g\in G \mid gs=s\}$, the isotropy group of s. It is stated that $N(G_s)/G_s$, where $N(G_s)=\{g\in G \mid g^{-1}G_sg=G_s\}$ is the normalizer of $G_s$,  is isomorphic to the group of G-automorphisms of $S$, $Aut_G(S)$.

This is a lemma in May's book "a concise course in  algebraic topology". The idea in the book is associate to every $\phi\in Aut_G(S)$ an element $[n]\in N(G_s)/G_s$, by  $\phi\to n$, where $n$ is such that $\phi(s)=ns$. It exists by transitivity of the action. Now, the problem is to show that $n\in N(G_s)$. In the book, it is shown that $n^{-1}hn\in G_s$ for all $h\in G_s$, or equivalently $n^{-1}G_sn\subseteq G_s$ and from this concluded $n\in N(G_s)$. So the question is: why is it not necessary to show that $G_s\subseteq n^{-1}G_sn$? Is it implicit in the argument?

By the way, in general there are cases in which  $ G_s$ contains $n^{-1}G_sn$ properly!

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^{-1}G_sn$ is equal to $G_{n^{-1}s} = G_{\phi^{-1}(s)}$, so $n^{-1}G_sn \le G_s$ is equivalent to $G_{\phi^{-1}(s)} \le G_s$. But $\phi^{-1} \in {\rm Aut}_G(S)$, so replacing $\phi$ by $\phi^{-1}$ gives $G_{\phi(s)} \le G_s$. So $nG_sn^{-1} \le G_s$ which implies $G_s \le n^{-1}G_sn$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So the trick was to use the fact that $Aut_G(S)$ is a group, I did not consider that. Still the relation $G_s\subseteq n^{-1}G_sn$, in the proper sence, seems hard to imagine in a specific example.

Comment: It can happen. The standard example of this is the group defined by the presentation $\langle x,y \mid y^{-1}xy=x^2 \rangle$ (it can alternatively be defined as a group of $2 \times 2$ rational matrices). Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $\langle x \rangle$. So $y^{-1}Hy$ is properly contained in $H$. By letting $G$ act by left multiplication on the left cosets $gH$ of $H$ in $G$, you can set this up as a transitive action in which $H$ is a stabilizer (i.e. isotropy group).